# Can i read context-param using a normal java class file form web.xml file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

Web.xml

```
    <param-name>driver</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>url</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql:///gts_user</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>user_name</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>gts</param-value>
</context-param>
```

i want get all value from web.xml using a java class file

Comment: No. The context will not be there in normal java file. You need the context to read param.

Comment: what i need ? plz specify

Comment: pass the servletcontext object to your java object constructor. Make sure that it won't affect the performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to get access to all those `context-param` elements if you have access to the `ServletContext`. You have access to the `ServletConfig` in a number of places, namely, `Servlet#init(..)`, `Filter#init(..)`, and most of the listener types.

The method you are looking for is [`ServletContext#getInitParameterNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameterNames%28%29).

Otherwise, you will have to parse the `web.xml` yourself.

Comment: ServleContext.getInitParameterNames() is not working in java class file

Comment: @AshishSrivastava Please re-read my answer. If you have access to the `ServletContext` provided by the Servlet container, you can use it. Otherwise, you will need to parse the `web.xml` yourself.

Comment: ohh  sorry tell me how can i get the path of web.xml file using java for parse it

Comment: @AshishSrivastava You can always get it relative to your current working directory. **I'll just say that that is a very bad idea and you shouldn't do it.** There is absolutely no reason you should.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava No. The only way you should do it is through the Servlet container provided `ServletContext`.

Comment: @as If you explained why you needed it, there might be a different solution.